# How to disable previous dates in Ui calendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, fullcalendar

I'm new to Ui calendar. I just wanna to know how to disable previous dates in Ui-calendar using angularjs. Eventdrop, EventResize and eventclick everything works fine for me and i wanna disable previous dates so that the events in the calendar cannot be dropped or resized to the previous dates! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the time period where events can dragged/dropped, set the `eventConstraint` property:

```
eventConstraint: {
  start: moment(),
  end: moment().add(100, 'years')
}
```

See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/eventConstraint/

However, this only covers dragging/dropping of *existing* events. That might be enough for you, but if you also need to restrict where the user can drag to create *new* events, you will need to specify the `selectConstraint` option in exactly the same way:

```
selectConstraint: {
  start: moment(),
  end: moment().add(100, 'years')
}
```

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/selectConstraint/

Note that setting `moment()` as the start will restrict dragging to literally the current instant in time (when the calendar is rendered to the browser). If you want to be a bit more liberal and allow anything on the current day, you could set it as:

```
start: moment().startOf('day')
```

Or to restrict to dates starting from *tomorrow*:

```
start: moment().startOf('day').add(1, "days")
```

See http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/ for more possibilities.

Comment: Thank you ADyson.

Answer (score 0):

by adding this below line codes ui.calendar config, it prevents events drop to previous dates

```
eventConstraint: {
        start: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
        end: '2100-01-01' // hard coded goodness unfortunately
    }
```